# Convert rfc3339 string to timestamp with timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.3

Is there any way to properly convert a rfc3339 string in a `character varying` column to a `timestamp with timezone`?

```
Input: "2015-01-28T17:41:52Z"
Expected output: "2015-01-28 17:41:52+00"
Current output: "2015-01-28 17:41:52+01"
```

I tried the following

```
/* begin dummy data */
WITH messages as (
    select 123 as id, '2015-01-28T17:41:52Z'::text as received
)
/* end dummy data */
SELECT id, received, (to_timestamp(received, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh24:MI:SS')) as d
FROM messages
```

Adding `TZ` or `tz` is not possible for input data and `OF` [is available in 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) but [not in 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE).

Comment: rfc3339 is just a profile of iso8601 -- PostregreSQL accepts any valid iso8601 input as `date`/`timestamp`/`timestamp with time zone`. (try casting `'2015-01-28T17:41:52Z'::timestamptz`)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll accept that as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) is just a profile of ISO 8601.

PostregreSQL [accepts any valid ISO 8601 input](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) as `date`/`timestamp`/`timestamp with time zone`. Try casting, like:

```
SELECT '2015-01-28T17:41:52Z'::timestamptz
```

*Note*: however, your output (in your client) will always be in your [current time zone](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html).